# same browser version across different Operating Systems

Tags: browser, windows-7, windows-vista, internet-explorer-9

I am on a MAC and am installing a few virtual machines with windows so that I can check browser compatibility.

Disclaimer I have licenses for all

Now I need to have a operating system with ie9 - Vista, 7, and the recently released beta of windows 8 can all handle that one. Will the browser display things differently because it is in a different OS?

I am already needing to install XP 2 times, to cover IE6 and IE8 (I know IE6 is outdated, but still being used a lot.)

Cheers for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a web developer as well and have my mac, a pc and 3 Virtual machines to test IE6-9. The operating systems should not matter. The browsers are coded to pretty much work the same no matter what OS (short of third party extension versions or changes in configuration settings). The only thing that would cause differences is if you are not declaring a <!DOCTYPE> In IE 6-9, if there is no Doctype it enters quirks mode. Quirks mode is basically what IE was at version 5 and earlier. It is the only browser that I have found to do this.

Comment: Of course the standard, each version has different css rulesets. So what might work in one might not work in another. IE has a tendency to be, at times, 6-12 months behind CSS standards. (My Opinion Only)

Comment: Cool thanks for the clarification. I didn't think there would be a difference, but with IE you never really know until its tested:-D Also I am going to code everything in strict or the future equivalent of those, as HTML 5 does not have those options yet - so the doctypes should not cause the issue.

Comment: HTML5 is built like HTML4 with XML/XHTML support and has no strict, transitional, or loose. And as far as when it becomes a standard, I believe there will not be any still. HTML5 is being built for ease of use and more functionality, from a developer stand point. I still code everything like I did for XHTML Strict and it works fine in HTML5. Plus only IE9 supports HTML5 only tags (nav, footer, header) with out the help of javascript, html5shiv.